# php - Adding an element form one array into another

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have 2 arrays like so:

```
$array1 = array(
    array("foo"=>"bar","count"=>"3"),
    array("foo2"=>"bar2","count"=>"4"),
    array("foo3"=>"bar3","count"=>"2")
);

$array2 = array(
    array("foo4"=>"bar","count"=>"3"),
    array("foo5"=>"bar2","count"=>"4"),
    array("foo6"=>"bar3","count"=>"2")
);
```

how can i add the 3rd element of array2 into array1 so it can become like this:

```
$array1 = array(
    array("foo"=>"bar","count"=>"3"),
    array("foo2"=>"bar2","count"=>"4"),
    array("foo3"=>"bar3","count"=>"2"),
    array("foo6"=>"bar3","count"=>"2")
);
```

i have tried doing `$array1 += $array2[2];` but it doesn't work. it just adds the keys from `array("foo6"=>"bar3","count"=>"2")` to array1 instead of adding it as an array in `$array1`

Could you help me out?

Comment: google php arrays and have a good read through what you find.

Comment: i don't get why my question is being down voted?

Comment: ^ This question does not show any research effort

Comment: how would a newbie know that its `$array1[] = $array2[2];` and not `$array1 = $array2[2];` ?? i have done my research and came across array_push() and array_merge(). It didn't work so i am asking here.

Comment: It's the basics before you get to array_push and array_merge. Start from the beginning not the middle. Poking at it with a stick is not how to learn how something works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[]` operator appends an element to the end of an array, like this

```
$array1[] = $array2[2];
```

Answer (score 4):

Just do like this:

```
$array1[] = $array2[2];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the exact 3rd item, then you could do something like:

```
$array1[] = $array2[2];
```

If you want the last item of the array, you can use:

```
$array1[] = $array2[count($array2)];
```

Comment: You could also use `$array1[] = end($array2);`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$array1[] = $array2[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

array_merge() is a function in which you can copy one array to another in PHP.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php